# change background color progressively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery code below. What it does it when user click on `.bx`, it clones `.bx` and insets it after clicked `.bx`. Now what I want is when `.bx` is added then the background of `.container` should change from light to darker(grey) **progressively**. I mean when second `.bx` is added after the first one then there should be a little change it `.container`'s color. When second is added then a little more change in the color should be added. I am trying `rgba` and changing the value of `a`, but it is not working(I am not sure why).

**How can I make this work?**

Here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5378W/)

Here is html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="bx"></div>    
</div>
```

Here is JS

```
var rand = 0;
$('body').on('click', '.bx', function (e) {
        var clone = $(this).clone();

        $(this).after(clone);

        $('.container').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, ' + getRandom() + ')');
    });

function getRandom(min, max) {
    return rand + 0.01;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding 0.01 to rand, but you aren't incrementing rand afterwards, so it returns the same thing every time:

```
rand += 0.01; // increment and save
return rand; // then return
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not updating `rand`. I have updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5378W/3/

```
function getRandom(min, max) {
    rand += 0.01;
    return rand;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
  var rand = 0;
  $('body').on('click', '.bx', function (e) {
    var clone = $(this).clone();
    $(this).after(clone);
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 254) + 1
    $('.container').css('background','rgb(255,'+getRandom(rand)+','+getRandom(rand)+')');
  });

  function getRandom(rand) {
   return parseInt(rand);
  }
```

Comment: Whats the difference then other answers?